# Polymer 3 + Webpack -> PolymerElement cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: webpack, polymer, babeljs, polymer-3.x

I'm testing the Polymer 3.0 preview code and want to setup a simple project with Webpack and Babel transforming it back to ES5.

The compilation is working fine. I added the custom-elements-es5-adapter.js to my demo page but the bundled code executes with following error:

```
custom-component.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor PolymerElement cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at HTMLElement.CustomComponent (custom-component.js:13)
    at new j (custom-elements-es5-adapter.js:4)
    at CustomElementRegistry.value (custom-elements-es5-adapter.js:4)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (custom-component.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6c5b87648fe743e36ebc:19)
    at window.JSCompiler_renameProperty (bootstrap 6c5b87648fe743e36ebc:62)
    at bootstrap 6c5b87648fe743e36ebc:62
```

ES6 Code is taken from here: https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-23-hands-on-30-preview

```
import {Element as PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element';

export class CustomComponent extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return `<div>This is my [[name]] app.</div>`
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = '3.0 preview';
    }

    static get properties() {
        name: {
            Type: String
        }
    }
}

customElements.define('custom-component', CustomComponent);
```

webpack.config.js

```
const {resolve} = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
        "custom-component": './custom-component.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

You can find the code in my Github Repo for a quick review: https://github.com/janrembold/webcomponent-examples/tree/master/06-frameworks/04-polymer

Does this error occur just because of the early state of Polymer3? Or do I miss something here?

By the way, I don't want to use polymer-cli because we have some special requirements in our project.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue:
I solved it by using `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` for the the browsers supporting native custom elements (safari and chrome).
And using `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack` for transpiling.

no transpiling:

`plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']`

transpiling:

`plugins: ['dynamic-import-webpack']`

Comment: What does your webpack loader configuration looks like please ? I still get the error.

Comment: Can you show me your webpack.js file and your errors?